# Limit Button Clicks Based on User Input

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a page wherein it uses to add rooms for admin, admin will choose the number of rooms he wants to add and then proceed to naming room id, problem is my button wont disable after the given number of quantity. If admin wants to add 5 rooms, then the button can only be clicked 5 times for adding of room, then after 5 times of clicking the button should be disabled. Here is my sample code.

```
int count = 0; // <-- Global Variable

protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(qtyDDL.SelectedValue);  // <--number of rooms admin wants to add
        count++;   
        roomtypeDDL.Enabled = false;
        qtyDDL.Enabled = false;
        if(count < qty)
        {
            string roomid = roomidBox.Text;
            string rtype = roomtypeDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            roomidBox.Enabled = false;
            roomtypeDDL.Enabled = true;
            addBtn.Enabled = false;
            addBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2A2A");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you display the count and the qty at your page. That way you can see which one is giving you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void qtyDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (qtyDDL.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                //My Code
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Count"] = 0; // <-- sets count to 0 every click on quantity
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }

 protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Count"]); // <-- set variable 
        roomtypeDDL.Enabled = false;
        qtyDDL.Enabled = false;
        string rtype, roomid;

        if(count < Convert.ToInt32(Session["qty"]))
        {
            string roomid = roomidBox.Text;
            string rtype = roomtypeDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        count++;

        if (count == Convert.ToInt32(Session["qty"])) // <--Disable Add Button
        {
            roomidBox.Enabled = false;
            roomtypeDDL.Enabled = true;
            roomtypeDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
            qtyDDL.SelectedIndex = 0;
            addBtn.Enabled = false;
            addBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2A2A");
        }
        Session["Count"] = count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use session because in asp.net the public var will return to initial value each request

```
  protected void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Count"]==null)
        {
            Session["Count"] = 0;
        }
        count = int.Parse(Session["Count"]);
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(qtyDDL.SelectedValue);  // <--number of rooms admin wants to add
        count++;
        roomtypeDDL.Enabled = false;
        qtyDDL.Enabled = false;
        if (count < qty)
        {
            string roomid = roomidBox.Text;
            string rtype = roomtypeDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        else
        {
            roomidBox.Enabled = false;
            roomtypeDDL.Enabled = true;
            addBtn.Enabled = false;
            addBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2C2A2A");
        }
        Session["Count"] = count;
    }
```

Comment: I have come up with an answer with the your code, but I think the way you set your 'Session["count"] = 0' is a little bit wrong, because it will set to 0 every click on addBtn so the if statement will keep running. But anyways thanks to your code it helped me a lot